# Jquery sort a list of checkboxes in the initial order after unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a list of checkboxes that are input alphabetically; some of them are already checked.
I want the checked checkboxes to go to the top of the list when the page loads and to revert to alphabetical order when a user unchecks a checkbox.
Although I've done something with my lame skills in JQuery, the checkboxes are not at the top of the list as you can see in the preview when the page loads.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $("#vm_table tbody");
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var tr = checkbox.closest("tr");

    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
      tr.prependTo(table);
    } else {
      table.find("tr").sort(function(a, b) {
        var tda = $(a).find("td:first-child").text();
        var tdb = $(b).find("td:first-child").text();
        return tda.localeCompare(tdb);
      }).appendTo(table);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="vm_table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">A-Z</th>
         <th scope="col">Class</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="218">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="218" class="displaynone" id="218">A
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="219">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="219" class="displaynone" id="219">B
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="221">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="221" class="displaynone" id="221">C
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A3<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="222">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="222" class="displaynone" checked="" id="222">D
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="223">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="223" class="displaynone" id="223">E
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="224">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="224" class="displaynone" checked="" id="224">F
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="225">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="225" class="displaynone" checked="" id="225">G
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            B2<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="226">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="226" class="displaynone" id="226">H
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="213">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="213" class="displaynone" id="213">I
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="216">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="216" class="displaynone" checked="" id="216">J
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            C3<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="217">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="217" class="displaynone" checked="" id="217">K
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            B1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="215">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="215" class="displaynone" id="215">L
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="220">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="220" class="displaynone" id="220">M
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="214">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="214" class="displaynone" id="214">N
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never order them, when the page first loads. You only order them in the change event.

You can order them on page load by adding this line

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("tr").prependTo(table);
```

like I did below.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $("#vm_table tbody");
  
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("tr").prependTo(table);

  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var tr = checkbox.closest("tr");

    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
      tr.prependTo(table);
    } else {
      table.find("tr").sort(function(a, b) {
        var tda = $(a).find("td:first-child").text();
        var tdb = $(b).find("td:first-child").text();
        return tda.localeCompare(tdb);
      }).appendTo(table);

    // Put the checked ones to the top of the table
   $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").closest("tr").prependTo(table);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="vm_table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">A-Z</th>
         <th scope="col">Class</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="218">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="218" class="displaynone" id="218">A
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="219">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="219" class="displaynone" id="219">B
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="221">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="221" class="displaynone" id="221">C
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A3<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="222">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="222" class="displaynone" checked="" id="222">D
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="223">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="223" class="displaynone" id="223">E
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="224">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="224" class="displaynone" checked="" id="224">F
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            A1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="225">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="225" class="displaynone" checked="" id="225">G
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            B2<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="226">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="226" class="displaynone" id="226">H
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="213">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="213" class="displaynone" id="213">I
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="216">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="216" class="displaynone" checked="" id="216">J
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            C3<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm background-color-secondary">
         <td>
            <label for="217">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="217" class="displaynone" checked="" id="217">K
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
            B1<br>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="215">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="215" class="displaynone" id="215">L
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="220">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="220" class="displaynone" id="220">M
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable_vm">
         <td>
            <label for="214">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vms" value="214" class="displaynone" id="214">N
            </label>
         </td>
         <td class="schedule-name" id="schname">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** Now the checked ones remain on top and the unchecked one returns into alphabetical order.

Comment: Yeah that will do, but when you unchecked just one checkbox it's reset the top list back into the inital alphabetic order.

Comment: The uncheck is the same behavior as your code in the question. So, you only want the unchecked one to go back into alphabetical order?